# How to Redirect www to non-www with Tomcat?

Tags: facebook, tomcat, authentication, configuration

I am using **facebook** application for user authentication in my Java based Web application but here i am getting one issue

I have added website like this http://www.example.com but someone will come in my website with  http://example.com Facebook login is not working..because facebook application set for  http://www.example.com

I tried to get solution of this problem then i got this [Redirect www to non-www with .htaccess file](http://eppand.com/redirect-www-to-non-www-with-htaccess-file/)  but they are using **Apache** for this

Can we configure Tomcat as well for this setting So facebook application work fine for each URL?

Answer (score 0):

You would write a servlet to handle www.example.com. All the code would do is redirect to example.com.

Comment: Do you mean its not possible to change Something in Tomcat? We have to write Servlet for this?

Comment: This is one way to do it. Looking around I found http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/tomcat-url-redirect-4175461611/